# Spring controller(A).method invoked controller(B).method but finds empty Model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

LoginFormController-->Post is invoked after the form is submitted/posted. At the end, it invokes another Controller called LandingFormController-->loadForm.

Well, in the loadForm the values in the Model seems to be empty. Is there a way I can persist a Bean in session or request and get it in the loadForm method? Bonus points: if you could point to some documents to refer :)

Thanks

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginFormController {  

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView post(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result, SessionStatus status) {
    logger.info("post");
    new ReceiptUserValidator().validate(user, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
    else {
        logger.info("Email Id: " + user.getEmailId());
        //status.setComplete();         

        Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        model.put("userId", user.getEmailId());
        model.put("now", new Date().toString());

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/landing.htm", "model", model);
    }
}
```

Controller B below that gets called

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/landing")
public class LandingFormController {    
    protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loadForm(Model model) {
        logger.info("LandingFormController loadForm: " + model.asMap().keySet());       
        return "landing";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is performing a redirect which causes the properties placed in the model to be lost.  Use flash attributes to pass the attributes to the next controller.

> Flash attributes provide a way for one request to store attributes
>   intended for use in another. This is most commonly needed when
>   redirecting — for example, the Post/Redirect/Get pattern. Flash
>   attributes are saved temporarily before the redirect (typically in the
>   session) to be made available to the request after the redirect and
>   removed immediately.

**LoginFormController**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/login")
public class LoginFormController {  

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView post(@ModelAttribute User user, BindingResult result,
      SessionStatus status, final RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {

    logger.info("post");
    new ReceiptUserValidator().validate(user, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return new ModelAndView("login");
    }
    else {
        logger.info("Email Id: " + user.getEmailId());
        //status.setComplete();         

        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("userId", user.getEmailId());
        redirectAttrs.addFlashAttribute("now", new Date().toString());

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/landing.htm", "model", model);
    }
}
```

[Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes)

As an alternative solution you could simply not perform a redirect from the controller.

Appending retrieving solution.

Modify the loadForm

```
 public String loadForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user) {
        logger.info("LandingFormController loadForm: " + user.getEmailId());        
        return "landing";
    }
```

Comment: @java_dude Excellent, glad I could help and could use some of my recent reading to benefit others.  Good question BTW it help so much when you post all of the code.

Comment: I have to perform redirect to change the link otherwise the link always says /login.htm. 

If there is another way to update the link I would prefer to do that without redirect.